# ActiveMQ Artemis REST - Produce a message along with Group ID through a POST call

Tags: rest, curl, activemq-artemis

Can someone please provide me a sample `curl` command to produce a message along with group id?

I have followed [official documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/2.9.0/rest.html) and created a war file and deployed it in my ActiveMQ Artemis installation, and I'm able to produce messages to my queue using REST call, e.g.:

```
curl --verbose --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{"Text":"hello"}" http://<IP_ADDR>:<PORT/artemis-rest/queues/MyQueue/create
```

And I can see the message being shown in the web console for `MyQueue`.

I have been trying to find a way to send group-id for this message in the `curl` request, but till now unsuccessful in doing that. I have tried to use `_AMQ_GROUP_ID` and `JMSXGroupId` a query parameter, request header, and body, but none of these actually is taken by the broker as a group id.

1. Send group-id as a query parameter:

   ```
   curl --verbose --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{"Text":"hello"}" http://<IP_ADDR>:<PORT/artemis-rest/queues/MyQueue/create?_AMQ_GROUP_ID=group-123
   ```
2. Send as header:

   ```
   curl --verbose --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "_AMQ_GROUP_ID: group-123" --data "{"Text":"hello"}" http://<IP_ADDR>:<PORT/artemis-rest/queues/MyQueue/create
   ```
3. Send as a body:

   ```
   curl --verbose --header "Content-Type: application/json"  --data "_AMQ_GROUP_ID=group-1&body={"Text":"hello"}" http://<IP_ADDR>:<PORT/artemis-rest/queues/MyQueue/create
   ```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using REST rather than something that's actually standard (and equally ubiquitous) like STOMP?

Answer (score 0):

We need to send `message.property._AMQ_GROUP_ID=<groupid>` in the headers section.

Comment: Please note that the REST interface was [removed in ActiveMQ Artemis 2.26.0](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/versions.html#2-26-0). See [here](https://lists.apache.org/thread/xbjmtk1o0q574rhz5yc3cz61jq0soy43) for more details on that. I _strongly_ recommend you use something like STOMP instead since it is based on an actual specification that's adopted across the industry. Using REST will make your applications/scripts difficult or impossible to port later.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).